# Using PyMOL API in python scripts and running them using Python

Tags: command-line, python3

I have PyMOL already installed on my Linux machine. I know it is installed because when I write `pymol -cp pymol_api_test.py` the script executes.

However, I don't want to execute the script using `pymol` command. I want to run the script using `python3` command.

The following is my script:

```
import pymol
from pymol import cmd

print(cmd.align("/home/bbq_spatial/bbq_input_pdb/pdb1a6j.pdb",  
                "/home/bbq_spatial/bbq_output_pdb/pdb1a6j.pdb", 
                cycles=0, transform=0))
```

It doesn't run when I call it using `python3`:

```
user_name@server_name:~$ nano pymol_api_test.py
user_name@server_name:~$ python3 pymol_api_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymol_api_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pymol
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymol'
user_name@server_name:~$
```

How can I resolve this?